# Is a “senior faculty member” of a university the same as a "senior professor"?

Tags: formal-language

But, as **one senior faculty member of the City University**, who spoke on condition of anonymity, puts it... He is obviously not fit for such a senior academic position. We don’t want ethics dumping here.”

This is a sentence from *The Economist* magazine, and the Chinese translation of the emboldened part equates it to "a senior professor".

I know that technically the term "faculty member" is different from "professor", but is it true that,in effect, only a "senior professor" is considered as a "senior faculty member"?

Answer (score 1):

Faculty and professors are both used in the education environment but the difference is as follows:

Faculty **includes** professors of various ranks,  lecturers, and/or researchers.

Researchers **who do not teach** or have educational responsibilities are not called professors.

Professors **have a teaching component** attached to their job responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have another question if you don't mind: What does "senior" mean as in "a senior faculty member" and "a senior professor"? Does it mean experienced or high-ranking?

Comment: Senior both mean high ranking or experienced.  Most likely in that context it means high ranking.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, "a senior professor" *in most circumstances* would be a reasonable translation of "a senior faculty member" when translating to a different language. A senior member of faculty is nearly always going to be a professor.

There can be circumstances where it would be less accurate. For instance, in the UK, professor does not have the meaning it does in most other places of 'any tenured or tenure track member of the teaching faculty', but 'possessor of a personal chair, head of department'. They are *the* most senior faculty members, and other faculty members, such as senior lecturers or 'readers', would also be considered 'senior'. A simpler way to think of it is that British professors are few in number and always senior, whereas you can be a junior (or 'associate') professor in other parts of the world, especially the US and Canada.